# unable to install package using "sudo pip install package"

Tags: apache, unix, flask, pip

I am trying to deploy Flask app on Unix system using Apache server.
Referring [link](https://dev.to/sm0ke/flask-deploy-with-apache-on-centos-minimal-setup-2kb7)

In order to deploy, virtual environment and project needs to be created inside **"/var/www/"** repository.
While doing this root access is required.

Now in order to install packages for this virtualenv from "/var/www/" location I am using

**"sudo pip install package"** --> **pip does not exists**

**"pip install package"**  --> **permission denied**

Is there any way to accomplish this task.

Comment: mostly pip preinstalled in Unix Systems checkout this for the same [https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/]. i think some problem in pip so try to run `pip` as  in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install package`

Comment: Thanks, But using this command giving following error                                              
**"pip is a package and can not be directly executed"**    I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

When you have a closer look at the tutorial, you are referring to, there is no mention of installing anything globally with pip.

Instead, the author of the tutorial uses best practices and creates a virtual environment first.

There are at least two good reasons for this:

- your environment is isolated from other packages
- you do not need root or sudo to install

So, be sure to follow the instructions, and create a virtual environment first.

The author does it this way

```
$ virtualenv --python=python3 hitme
```

Then activate it exactly like it is described.

That all said, you certainly can put your flask app into `/var/www`, but this is just the author's preference. You could also put it e.g. in a subfolder of your home directory.

Comment: Thanks, But I tried to put flask app at **/home/ec2-user/ with providing all (777)** permissions I am getting **Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource (403 error)**  since these files are not reachable for the server

Comment: Have you tried to create the virtualenv? If you are unsure where to create it, please consult the documentation of your hoster. Also, just as a side note, never ever set permissions to 777 - this would mean that anybody with access to the server is able to modify the contents of this directory.